# how to change class from an external page

Tags: javascript, html

What method changes a class value from an external page using javascript? For instance, I'd like to change:

```
<div class="new-button disabled" style="height: 50px;">OK</div>
```

to

```
<div class="new-button" style="height: 50px;">OK</div>
```

Comment: [`classList.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)?

Comment: If by _"from an external page"_ you mean you want the script on your page to change stuff on other pages from different domains, that you show via (i)frame/popup/..., then the answer is: None does. Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 0):

**element.classList.remove()** will remove the class you want to remove.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('new-button')[0].classList.remove("disabled");
```

please refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for more information

you can also add(), toggle() the class you want